# How to reference the current column you are defining using lag?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a salary table like this:

```
declare @t table (OrderedID int, EmpID int, EffDate date, Salary money)

insert into @t
values
(1,1234,'20150101',100)
,(2,1234,'20160101',100)
,(3,1234,'20170101',100)
,(4,1234,'20180101',300)
,(1,2351,'20150101',100)
```

I am trying to get an initial effective date on each row:

First 3 rows have 1/1/2015

4th row has new value 1/1/2018

Here is what I tried with a case and a lag but i can't figure out how to reference the prior value of the column I am creating.

```
case when OrderedID = 1 then EFFDaTe
          when Salary != LAG(Salary,1) then EFFDaTe
          else lag(SalaryEFFDT,1) over (order by 1)
end as SalaryEFFDT
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What is your desired output?

Comment: Lag is not appropriate for this use, since it only looks 'back' one row. You need to use a subquery like `SELECT MIN(EffDate) from @t as t WHERE t.OrderId = @t.OrderId and t.Salary = @t.Salary.`. Note that this will not work where a person's salary changes, then changes back to a previous salary value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you haven't provided the expected output, I think this is what you want:

```
declare @t table (OrderedID int, EmpID int, EffDate date, Salary money)

insert into @t
values
(1,1234,'20150101',100)
,(2,1234,'20160101',100)
,(3,1234,'20170101',100)
,(4,1234,'20180101',300)
,(1,2351,'20150101',100)
,(5,1234,'20190101',100)

;with cte as
(Select *, OrderedId - Row_Number() over (partition by EmpId,Salary order by OrderedID) as grp
from @t)
, cte1 as
(Select EmpID, grp, min(effDate) as effDate from cte c group by EmpID, grp)
Select OrderedID, t.EmpID, t.EffDate, t.Salary, c.effDate as computeddate 
from cte t join cte1 c on t.EmpID = c.EmpID and t.grp = c.grp
order by OrderedID
```

Comment: This is right. I thought I was clear with expected results. it 's the source data I provided with one extra column.

Answer (score 0):

So you are trying to get the first effective date for each EmpID? the code below should do that. If that is not your desired output can you put what the output should look like?

```
declare @t table (OrderedID int, EmpID int, EffDate date, Salary money)

insert into @t
values
(1,1234,'20150101',100)
,(2,1234,'20160101',100)
,(3,1234,'20170101',100)
,(4,1234,'20180101',300)
,(1,2351,'20140101',100)
,(2,2351,'20150101',100)


Select
T.*,FE.FirstEff
From @t T
inner join (Select EmpID,MIN(EffDate) as FirstEff from @t group by
```

The second set is if you need the first time they have that salary, however you will have issues if someone gets a raise and then a demotion.

```
Select
T.*,FE.FirstEff
From @t T
inner join (Select EmpID,Salary,MIN(EffDate) as FirstEff from @t group by EmpID,Salary) FE on FE.EmpID = T.EmpID
    and FE.Salary = T.Salary
```